# SSRS Incremented column headings

Tags: reporting-services

I'm creating a report using SSRS. I have a matrix where the row is grouped by Date. I want the  column headings to just display a number value, which increments everyime from 0 - 23. How would i achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume 0-23 is the hour portion of the datetime? Use the datepart function to extract the hour. If you share your SQL I can elaborate further.